# Sending data to php from jquery

Tags: php, jquery

have a question and I hope that you can help me with it. I have two file *frame.js* and *up.php*. *frame.js* take data from inputs (work correctly), and sent to *up.php*.

Frame.js

```
    //some code

     $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
         url: "up.php",
         data: { 
               login: login;
               pass: pass},
         success : function() {
                alert('success');
                close_frame (); 
     }
     });
```

up.php

```
<?php
  echo('reg start');   //message to check that it work
  echo ('<script>alert('reg start');</script>'); // another varient to check
  if ((isset($_POST['login'])) 
 //some code
?>
```

SO jquery sent information to up.php. But is up.php launch automatically or what I need to do to make the up.php to take the data from jquery file?

Answer (score 1):

The up.php will run and all the data send via the ajax will be receive in the

```
$_POST
```

So basically you do need to do anything to make  the data available in the php because it's already available
But notice that you are not doing anything with the response (the 2 echos) so you will have to open the firebug/console in order to see the prints

Comment: can you help me to make the echo work... that I can see that messages

Answer (score 1):

You can access any variables you send through `$_POST` in up.php.

You should know that jQuery has a built in function for POST ajax requests:

```
$.POST(url, data)
.done(function(response){
    alert(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should process response from up.php in success function. Something like $(body).html(arguments[0])